# Sahi : File:// protocol support in Sahi

Tags: sahi, file-uri

I am evaluating Sahi for automation. My requirement is to automate a web application that is static and based on Html and JavaScript.
I tried to record the test but it did not happen.

file:///C:/Automation/welcome.html

But Sahi doesn't record it. I saw on [url]http://sahi.sourceforge.net/using.html[/url] site that only ##Keep "Use the same proxy for all protocol" unchecked as Sahi does not understand protocols other than HTTP##

Does File:// or other protocols support is not been provided yet?
Please let me know is there any alternative Sahi provides for such requirement?
I could not find it on any forum, please help.
Thanks

Comment: When you say "yet", I don't think there is any plan to... For sahi to even be a valid test tool you need to use it over http... which is what it is built for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use a webserver to open your pages and then access it through Sahi.
Sahi will not able to automate pages with the file protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **WAMP** or **XAMPP** server in your system, and then put the html file in the local server directory and after that you can access your html page by http://localhost:port/welcome.html and then you can use **Sahi Pro** for recording and playback.

Instead of  **WAMP** or **XAMPP**, you can use **EasyPhp** too.